# How to push a view into an existing table cell?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've got a nice table populated with data, with custom-designed cell layouts. Currently, tapping a cell will push in a new view (for more information, say), which works fine.

What I'd like to do, though, is have the new view push *into* the cell's bounds, not fill up the whole screen. Can't seem to wrap my brain around how to accomplish this -- any pointers you could offer?

Thanks! :)

Update: Here's some of the code, in case that helps the helpers:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FlippedViewController *flippedViewController = [[FlippedViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlippedView" bundle:nil];

// What goes in here? Where do contentView and originalView come from?

[originalView removeFromSuperview];
[contentView addSubview:flippedViewController.view];

[flippedViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hook in `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` (a method of [`UITableViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)) which uses a pointer to the particular cell's `contentView`, and performs the changes on that `UIView` just as it would any other.

For example, if you wanted to simply replace `originalView` (assuming that's what's in the cell now) with `newView`, you could do something like this:

```
// Use your own data structure and indexPath to retrieve contentView.
[originalView removeFromSuperview];
[contentView addSubview:newView];
```

That would update the view without an animation.

About the animation -- here are two related previous questions:

- [`UIView` based animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528098/uiview-based-animation)
- [Animating the display of a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026403/animating-the-display-of-a-view)

Comment: Okay, we're getting somewhere, thanks. Bear with my noviceness here for a sec...

Right now, inside `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, I've got this:
`[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.editView animated:YES];`
Where would I find out what my analogs for your `originalView`, `contentView`, and `newView` are?

Comment: Every UITableViewCell has its own UIView called contentView.  You'd have to store a map from table row# (and maybe section#) to the contentView's so you can look that up.  Depending on your setup, you might only have one visible UIView as a child of contentView - that would be your originalView.  And newView is whatever you want to show up in its place - based on your comment, it sounds like you want self.editView to be the replacement, assuming that's a UIView object.

Comment: I've been working on this all night, and am still a little stymied, alas. I can't seem to find out how to reference the `contentView` of the current cell. I've got the new view all set up and ready to add as a subview, but... I'll paste some code into the question above, see if that helps? Thanks again!